# How can I add readonly attribute at a control inside itemtemplate of Gridview by using code behind?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, webforms

How can I add readonly attribute at a control inside itemtemplate of Gridview by using code behind?
I have tried using rowdatabound but always get null

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e){
if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
    Textbox mytxt = e.Row.FindControl("txtDate") as Textbox;
}
}
```

I tried add readonly attribute in asp.net page but i cant get the textbox value(i use javascript calendar to input the textbox)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e){
    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        TextBox mytxt = e.Row.FindControl("txtDate") as TextBox;
        mytxt.Attributes.Add("readonly", "readonly");
    }
}
```